# Android app login and and Signin issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication

I am developing an android app in which , a sigin , and signup option is there . when a new user enters to the application for first time he needs to signup.. when he presses the sigin option he is directed to the account creation page.where he needs to gve the username,password and mobile number. all these three values are stored in sqlite ( applications memory ) and a passcode is created and send to the mobile number provided by user. and next page is registration page, where users username and password is checked along with the passcode which he recieved. This process I did to verify the mobile number. So my problem is if once the user created the account and go back to signin option and enter the username and password .. he is directing to the applications first page... because when account creation process is done his details are saved in the applications databse for verification. so user dont need to verify the passcode.. so is there any way to make the signin button view only after a registration process.. or something like that ... I am posting here the siginactivity, signupactivity and register activity.. pls  check it and if found any error pls help me...

Signup Activity

```
public class SignUpActivity extends Activity

{

    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editMobileNumber;
    Button btnCreateAccount;



    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();




    Random r = new Random();
    int number =r.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;



    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;


private static String url_create_data = "http://iascpl.com/app/create_data1.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_xm);



        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
                loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
                loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

                // Get References of Views


                editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
                editMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);




                btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);

                btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String name=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        String phoneNo = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
                        String sms = Integer.toString(number);


                        //Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                        //intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                        //startActivity(intent);



                        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();


                        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
                        while (st.hasMoreElements())

                        {

                            String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                            if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && sms.trim().length()>0) 
                            {
                                sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, sms);

                            }


                            else 

                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }





                        }








                        // check if any of the fields are vacant
                        if(name.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Save the Data in Database
                           loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(name, password);
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passcode is sent to the mobile number you provided. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     


                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();

                           // Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                          //  intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                           // startActivity(intent);



                        }







                    }
                });

    }









    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

      //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


    }













    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating a new account..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {





            String name = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String mobile = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            String sms = Integer.toString(number);

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_data,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product




                    Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                    i.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                    startActivity(i);

                    //closing this screen
                    //finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    return "false";



                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        /*protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }*/


        protected void onPostExecute(String result)

        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        if (result == "false")
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Name already exists. Please choose another user name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pDialog.dismiss();

        }


    }





}
```

Register Activity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {


    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    Button btnReg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_xm);


        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();



        btnReg = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonRegister);

        final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
        final  EditText editTextMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String mobileNumber = editTextMobileNumber.getText().toString();

                // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);



                String sd = getIntent().getStringExtra("number"); 
                String name = editTextUserName.getText().toString();



                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword) && (mobileNumber.equals(sd))) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congrats: Registration Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    Intent in = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);



                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Name, Passcode or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });


    }







@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
     {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();

      }
    }
```

Signin activity

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity 


{
    /*LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;*/
    Button btnsignin;
    EditText username,userpassword;

    TextView txtName;


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();



    // single product url
    private static String url_get_name = "http://iascpl.com/app/get_name_details.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin_xm);


        /*loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();*/

        btnsignin = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button401);
        username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText401);
        userpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText402);


        btnsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                new GetProductDetails().execute();

               /* String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);*/


                 // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                /*if(password.equals(storedPassword)) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    Intent i = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);




                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }*/



            }
        });
    }



        class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading the result... Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting product details in background thread
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) 


            {
                String pid=username.getText().toString();











                            // Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));





                            // getting product details by making HTTP request
                            // Note that product details url will use GET request
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_get_name, "GET", params);



                            // check your log for json response
                            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());


                            // json success tag

                            try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully received product details
                                JSONArray productObj = json
                                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                                // get first product object from JSON Array
                                final JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                                txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                                // product with this pid found
                                // Edit Text
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() 
                                    {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try {
                                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_PASSWORD));

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                            }else{
                                // product with pid not found

                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }




                    return null;
                }


/*
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
     {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
      }*/


                            /**
                             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                             * **/
                            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
                            {
                                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                                /*super.onPostExecute(result);
                                if (result == "false")
                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User Name already exists. Please choose another user name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }



            }
    }
```

Comment: actually what you want please be more clear

Comment: now there is two buttons signin and signup.. on signup process username and password is saved and a passcode is sent to the mobile number provided.. next is registration page where user has to enter the username and password along with passcode.. this process i gave to verify the mobile number. but.. when username and passcode is saved so if user press back button and press the sigin button he dont need to regiser with the passcode because..username and passcode is already saved...

Comment: after registration just save a random value isUserPresent in that database and on sigin button click check this value. If it is 1 then user will not go to register page otherwise sent it to that page

Comment: thanks Avinash.. can u pls give me the code or can u pls share the link for that

Comment: you saving value in database or shared preference???

Comment: actually I am saving values in both MySQL and Sqlite... but for verifictaion I am using only sqlite value... the details saved in MySql is only for storing in database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40944/discussion-between-avinash-kumar-pankaj-and-roshanpeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your problem ... You are saving your signup details in sqlite so when user entering username and password it is saved in sqlite and next step is registration process where user has to enter the secret code.. But as as username and password is saved in sqlite user can press back button and go back and login with username and password and avoid registration process...
Here you can do something like this. use shared preference

for ex:In registration page after successful registration give value l.

```
 SharedPreferences set = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = set.edit(); 
                        ed.putString("l", "l"); 
                        ed.commit();
```

and check in your home page whether the value is l or not if value is l only then make your signin button visible. You can use something like this for making the button invisible.

```
btn3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 btn4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```